# Angular 6 elements and exporting styles from angular.json

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using primeng in a component with which I create a custom element. All is well, the primeng modules seem to work, but the primeng styles (and other styles for that matter) I put in angular.json are not included within the exported stylesheet. I tried putting including it in the scss of the component, including the styles within the html of the component and on the html of the page I will put the element on, but none of these work..

This makes it kind of unworkable. What would be the proper way to include vendor sylesheets to Angular 6 Elements?

Comment: it is not imported or you can't see applied style? could it be due to dom shadowing?

Comment: I tried many different things now and what you said that was part of the solution. I wanted to use ViewEncapsulation.Emulated, which if I understand correctly makes the element enherit css classes from the page. But then Primeng did not work. When I used ViewEncapsulation.Native primeng works, but all styles in angular.json and the parent page are ignored so I had to include all this in my component styles.Still primeicons did not work, so I added it on the parent page (don't understand why that worked), now I have to change all my child component styles to work with ViewEncapsulation.Native